# Sorting models in Django Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have two models one is a Lease model that has fields like `address`, `prefix`, `start_time` etc. The second is a Sub model that has fields such as `range`, `subnet`, `prefix`. What I need is to sort the leases into the Subs they belong in based on the Sub's range field.

I have added fields to both for comparison. These fields are `addr_cut`, `addr_end` for Lease and `range_low_cut`, `range_low_end`, and `range_high_end` for Sub.

What I am trying to do that is failing is this:

```
    {%for lease in leases%}
         {%for sub in subs%}
             {%if lease.addr_cut in sub.range_low_cut%}
                 {%if lease.addr_end >= sub.range_low_end%}
                     {%if lease.addr_end <= sub.range_high_end%}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{lease.DUID_text }}</td>
                            <td>{{lease.addr_text}}</td>
                            <td>{{lease.pub_date}}</td>
                            <td>{{lease.e_date}}</td>
                            <td>{{lease.prefix}}</td>

                        </tr>

                    {%endif%}
                {%endif%}
            {%endif%}
        {%endfor%}
    {%endfor%}
```

Now if I display the contents of `lease.addr_cut` and `sub.range_low_cut`:

```
2605:7300:201:3: 2605:7300:201:3:
```

Looks like the first `if` should get the green light right? Wrong. It fails for every check regardless of whether the contents are the same. I am new and I know that I am probably trying to introduce too much logic into the template but it seems like this is display based so it belongs here.

So my question. If it is a matter of too much logic in the template where and how should I implement this logic to sort my leases into the subnets they belong. Or maybe it is simply execution error and a kind stranger can point out my syntax errors. Thank you all.

Models for reference as requested:

```
class Lease(models.Model):
    DUID_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    addr_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    e_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    addr_cut = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    addr_end = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.addr_cut

class Sub(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subnet = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rang = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    range_low_cut = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    range_low_end = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    range_high_cut = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    range_high_end = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.range_low_cut
```

Success! Thanks to all who took the time to look into this. Following the link copied in the answer by David has me where I need to be.

Comment: last line you have a missing `}`, and also where do you close those tags? as in `{% endif %}, {% endfor %}`?

Comment: Sorry, I left out the rest of the code for brevity, my mistake on the missing `}`. The code runs fine and throws no errors just does not give me expected output.

Comment: Can you show how your models are?

Comment: There you go. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're not showing all the code, the snippet is missing a closing tag and it should read

```
{%for lease in leases%}
     {%for sub in subs%}
         {%if lease.addr_cut in sub.range_low_cut%}
             {%if lease.addr_end >= sub.range_low_end%}
                 {%if lease.addr_end <= sub.range_high_end%}
```

You code have another issue that makes it more complicate to maintain.

I discourage using nested if. You might refactor it as follow

```
{%for lease in leases%}
     {%for sub in subs%}
         {%if lease.addr_cut in sub.range_low_cut and
              lease.addr_end >= sub.range_low_end and
              lease.addr_end <= sub.range_high_end%}
```

Going further you might move the ifs into a function for increased clarity:

```
{%for lease in leases%}
    {%for sub in subs%}
        {% build_table lease sub %}
    {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}

@register.simple_tag
def build_table(lease, sub):
    {%if lease.addr_cut in sub.range_low_cut and
         lease.addr_end >= sub.range_low_end and
         lease.addr_end <= sub.range_high_end%}

        return """
            <tr>
                <td>{{lease.DUID_text }}</td>
                <td>{{lease.addr_text}}</td>
                <td>{{lease.pub_date}}</td>
                <td>{{lease.e_date}}</td>
                <td>{{lease.prefix}}</td>
            </tr>
        """
    {%endif%}
```

Look also at http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html for another example.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will refactor those if statements as suggested. If you can give me a quick pointer. Assuming I cannot place functions in the template where should I put the function? Inside the views/ context? Apologies I am new to django and trying to wrap my head around where to tie things in still.

Comment: http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html I think this is probably the direction I need to head in.

Comment: that tutorial is a good starting point. I'm updating my answer for future reference

Comment: `build_table(lease, sub) `--> does Django support parentheses in templates?

Comment: I don't believe so. I have gotten (almost) everything figured out by following the link guide on custom filters.

Comment: @Lemayzeur you're right. I updated the answer using the simple tag